# How to handle 404 client exception in python

Tags: python, http, httpresponse

API is returning the data if data is available or it is throwing 404client error, trying handle the exception but getting error's like
imported both modules.
1.

```
import requests and from urllib3 import response 
def test_methods:
try: 
dvcresppnse = "url/endpoint"      
dvcresppnse.raise_for_status()
/* rest of the code */
except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as e:
self.log.exception(e.response.text)
```

If the data is available api getting the response but it is not executing the code.When api is doesn't return any value it is passing mean exception is handling. but when api return data or fetch the data getting below error
I tried but am getting below error.
dvcresponse.raise_for_status()
ETypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
//using my response only trying to access raise_for_status() method but getting Typeerror
response.raise_for_status()
EAttributeError: module 'requests.packages.urllib3.response' has no attribute 'raise_for_status'
// not sure this is right or not but using response object trying to access raise_for_status() method getting attribute error.
can someone please help me how to handle 404 error when api return data and as well as "No data response"

Comment: You can use 
`except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as e:
        if response.status_code == 404:
else:`
        Rest of your code

Comment: Hi @Naruto, thank you for your response and for solution, Now it is working in both the condition. if dvcresponse.status_code == 404:
                dvcresponse.raise_for_status()

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests

def test_method():
    try:
        url = "url/endpoint"
        response = requests.get(url)
        response.raise_for_status()  # Raises an exception for 4xx and 5xx status codes
        data = response.json()  # Assuming the response contains JSON data
        # Process the data here
    except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as e:
        if e.response.status_code == 404:
            print("API returned a 404 error: Not Found")
        else:
            print("API returned an error:", e)
    except Exception as e:
        print("An error occurred:", e)

# Call the function to test
test_method()
```